# Replace HTML entities in a string avoiding <img> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have the following input:

```
Hi! How are you? <script>//NOT EVIL!</script>

Wassup? :P

LOOOL!!! :D :D :D
```

Which is then run through emoticon library and it become this:

```
Hi! How are you? <script>//NOT EVIL!</script>

Wassup? <img class="smiley" alt="" title="tongue, :P" src="ui/emoticons/15.gif">

LOOOL!!! <img class="smiley" alt="" title="big grin, :D" src="ui/emoticons/5.gif"> <img class="smiley" alt="" title="big grin, :P" src="ui/emoticons/5.gif"> <img class="smiley" alt="" title="big grin, :P" src="ui/emoticons/5.gif">
```

I have a function that escapes HTML entites to prevent XSS. So running it on raw input for the first line would produce:

```
Hi! How are you? &lt;script&gt;//NOT EVIL!&lt;/script&gt;
```

Now I need to escape all the input, but at the same time I need to preserve emoticons in their initial state. So when there is `<:-P` emoticon, it stays like that and does not become `&lt;:-P`.

I was thinking of running a regex split on the emotified text. Then processing each part on its own and then concatenating the string together, but I am not sure how easily can Regex be bypassed? I know the format will always be this:

```
[<img class="smiley" alt="]
[empty string]
[" title="]
[one of the values from a big list]
[, ]
[another value from the list (may be matching original emoticon)]
[" src="ui/emoticons/]
[integer from Y to X]
[.gif">]
```

Using the list MAY be slow, since I need to run that regex on text that may have 20-30-40 emoticons. Plus there may be 5-10-15 text messages to process. What could be an elegant solution to this? I am ready to use third-party library or jQuery for this. PHP preprocessing is possible as well.

Comment: Are the emoticons placed in JavaScript? Why you don't do that in PHP too so you can `htmlentities()` before that and have a simplier, safer and cleaner solution? You would even reduce both band and CPU usage with that.

Comment: And emoticons that use special symbols, you can simply make your script understand that `&lt;:-P` is the emoticon, instead of `<:-P`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

```
//TODO:Add the rest of emoticons here
var regExpEmoticons = /(\:P|\:\-P|\:D|\:\-D)/img;

function emoticonTag(title, filename) {
    return "<img class=\"smiley\" alt=\"\" title=\"" + title + "\" src=\"ui/emoticons/" + filename + "\">";
}

function replaceEmoticon(emoticon) {
    switch (emoticon.toUpperCase()) {
    case ':P':
    case ':-P':
        return emoticonTag("tongue, :P", "15.gif");
    case ':D':
    case ':-D':
        return emoticonTag("big grin, :D", "5.gif");
    //TODO: Add more emoticons
    }
}

function escapeHtml(string) {
    //TODO: Insert your HTML escaping code here
    return string;
}

function escapeString(string) {
    if (string == "") {
        return string;
    }
    var splittedString = string.split(regExpEmoticons);

    var result = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < splittedString.length; i++) {
        if (splittedString[i].match(regExpEmoticons)) {
            result += replaceEmoticon(splittedString[i]);
        } else {
            result += escapeHtml(splittedString[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

There are 3 places you must change:

1. Add all your emoticons to the `regExpEmoticons` variable.
2. Add all your emoticons to the `switch` statement of the `replaceEmoticon` function, or change the whole function for the one you have for replacing only the emoticon string into the HTML string containing the  tag.
3. Add your HTML escaping code into the `escapeHtml` function, or change the call to this function to the one you are using.

After that, if you call `escapeString` method with your string, I think it will do the work.